# Integrating VLC-QT with QT

Tags: c++, qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

I am having problems integrating the vlc-qt library with the qt creator.

Following the [derekmolly](http://derekmolloy.ie/custom-video-streaming-player-using-libvlc-and-qt/) website example, I have downloaded the vlc-qt library and extract it to the C:\Qt directory. Upon running the project named demo project located in the example folder, I have this error that says

> vlc-qt.lib(vlc-qt.dll):-1: error: LNK1112: module machine type 'x64'
>   conflicts with target machine type 'X86' File not found
>   vlc-qt.lib(vlc-qt.dll).

I have added the following in my src.pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\libvlc-qt_0.9.0_win64_msvc2012\include
LIBS     += -LC:\Qt\libvlc-qt_0.9.0_win64_msvc2012\lib -lvlc-qt-widgets -lvlc-qt
```

Why is this so? Please advice.

Thank you

Comment: You are building 32-bit and libraries are 64 bit.

Comment: I am using the Qt5.3.1 windows version. Is there a way to build it in 64 bit?

Comment: @joylamb Check `Tools->Options->Build & Run`.

Comment: Even if i am using a 32bit Qt I am able to select and choose to build in 64 bit?